# Google Cloud Powershell Test-GcsBucket killing process

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-sdk, google-cloud-powershell

Installed GCloud SDK components

- Google Cloud SDK 434.0.0
- bq 2.0.93
- core 2023.06.02
- gke-gcloud-auth-plugin 0.5.3
- gsutil 5.24

If I run the following:

`Test-GcsBucket -Name blahblah`

It immediately returns true and then a second or 2 later i get **[process exited with code 2 (0x00000002)]**.  This is killing the Terminal window. The knock on effects are that our deployment scripts are no longer working.

Any ideas what could be happening here?

**UPDATE**
This is being caused by my piHole blocking something being called from the Test-GcsBucket commandlet or whatever it uses lower in the stack.

Why is this killing the process? If it cant hit the endpoint for tracking or whatever, it should not kill the process. Not best pleased